# JavaFX - Множество кнопок с одинаковым действием

Tags: javafx

Есть несколько кнопок записанных в `FXML` файле, и всем им задано `onAction = "setWall"`

Как при нажатии на любую из кнопок обращаться к нажатой кнопке?

Comment: Упущен знак решетки "#": `onAction = "#setWall"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
public void setWall(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (actionEvent.getSource() instanceof Button) {
        Button button = (Button) actionEvent.getSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: Перепутал Event, изменил.